# How to use Core Data from RestKit when not using web services?

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit

I see RestKit can integrate Core Data when getting or updating objects from network or web services.

My questions is: How do I have to use that Core Data when I don't want to use RestKit (or web services)? Maybe I just want a table to show the objects I have saved locally.
Is that possible?

I see there are several patterns to use Core Data.

1. http://www.objc.io/issue-2/common-background-practices.html
2. http://cutecoder.org/programming/multithreading-core-data-ios/
3. http://www.slideshare.net/Inferis/adventures-in-multithreaded-core-data (root=main or root=private)

How do I have to use the Core Data database used (and configured) by RestKit?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If you don't want to use RestKit with Core Data then... just don't use it. Core Data has its own API that can be used directly.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Some request will use Core Data automatically, others don't use it, and some parts of the program, when not using networking, have to access Core Data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RestKit configures the Core Data stack for you. It creates a main context that you use for all of your UI. It creates a background context for all of the network related updates that it makes. It also gives you the ability to create new contexts that are associated with the persistent store context (that it creates as the parent for all contexts) if you require them.

With this set of functionality your app can do pretty much anything.

Note that you can seed the database when first created so you shouldn't really need to do lots of background operations for addition of content, only if you have time consuming fetch requests to execute.

Comment: So, can my program use that background context when using core data (but not network)? Your second point is also interesting to me, do you mean something like: http://www.objc.io/issue-4/importing-large-data-sets-into-core-data.html

Comment: There isn't just 1 background context, there are many depending on what's happening. You can't use them directly yourself (you create a new MOC specifically for the background thread you created to do some work). Yes, it is similar to that (based on my memory from when I read it)...